# Is it posssible to change "beep" sound programmatically on iPhone calling a number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am into an application on iPhone in which user type some phone number, the app will call it.

Is it possible to change programmatically the "beeep - beeep ..." sounds while the other part will not answer?

As still as I understand it's impossible for ringtone, but maybe for the dialing it's possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your iPhone app, you can set the sound to anything you like.  Then you can pass the number to the telephone.app to connect the phone call.  But you cannot change the system sound of the telephone.app.